# How to print Sqlite cursor log in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, logging, cursor

```
Cursor cursor = null;
db.openDatabase();
cursor = db.execQuery("select person_id, person_name" + " from person_table where person_id in (" + stringBuffer.toString() + ") order by person_name_jp asc");
```

code as above

then  how can I print the cursor's string ("select person_id,person_name from person_table where ...") to logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your cursor using `cursor.moveToNext()` or `cursor.moveToPosition(position)` manually or inside the cycle.

Get from cursor required data and just put it into Log:

```
Log.v("your_tag", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(person_name)));
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Comment: no,I mean the query string.   how to print the query string?

Comment: `Cursor cursor = null;
db.openDatabase();
String query = "select person_id, person_name" + " from person_table where person_id in (" + stringBuffer.toString() + ") order by person_name_jp asc";
cursor = db.execQuery(query);
Log.v("your_tag", query);`

Answer (score 0):

Assign your query string to a temporary string object which you pass to `executeQuery` and simply use `Log.i()` to print you query in logs:

```
String query="your query";
Log.i("your tag", query);
```

Comment: no,I mean the query string?   how to print the query string?

Comment: Updated answer , sorry i misunderstood ur question